# How to add iPhone SDK classes to autocomplete in TextMate?

Tags: iphone, textmate

How, if possible, can I have iPhone SDK's classes (UI*) to autocomplete inside TextMate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after looking the link Kendall posted and some other places this is what I have found:

There is currently NO easy way to have autocomplete of iPhone APIs in TextMate.

The link on the post Kendall pointed is old, but I found it and one other iPhone Bundle on gitHub:
http://github.com/Caged/gtbfm-textmate-bundle
http://github.com/drnic/objective-c-iphone-tmbundle

But none of these bundles offers autocomplete, they have some templates and snippets.

The closest I have found is on the svn repository from TextMate:
http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/iPhone.tmbundle

It's not official yet, and I have reported some issues with it to the developer (Joachim Mårtensson).
You can have autocomplete with this bundle, but it is working only with classes files, not headers.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the link at the bottom of this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-toolbox-for-mac/browse_thread/thread/e097e998674231fa